# reading windows registry with lua

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua for Windows.
Windows 8.1
Lua 5.1

I've added Steve Donovan's winapi module to it.
I want to be able to read/write from the Windows registry.
I'm getting inconsistent results with the winapi module.

I can read `[[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\DateTime\Servers]]` using `winapi.open_reg_key`; this is in the examples file with winapi.
If I remove "\Servers", sometimes it works, sometimes it returns null and "operation completed successfully".

I really want to read my own key at `[[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\LastName\MyStuff]]`.
If I rename the "MyStuff" key and then use `winapi.create_reg_key`, it fails, but open_reg_key works when I rename the key back.
I'm really at a loss.

Is there some other binary I can use to access the windows registry?

Comment: I found part of my problem.  Since I'm running a 32bit version of Lua, and 64bit version of Windows, the Winapi module is being redirected to a Wow6432Node section of the registry.

Comment: Write it up as the answer and accept it. You may need to wait a bit before accepting it.

Comment: Are saying that registry redirection is a problem in your program or just _was_ in your understanding of its incidental behavior?

Comment: My understanding of how x32 LUA worked on a X64 Windows was incorrect.

Comment: BTW—Your "x32" is little odd, too. x86 refers to 8086, 80186, 80286, 80386, 80485, .... X64 means x86 extended to 64 bits (as opposed to the short-lived IA-64, which was not compatible with x86 software).

Answer (score 3):

Lua for Windows, as of Sept 29, 2014, is 32-bit.  Writing to the registry with a 32 bit program doesn't work as I expected.  Specifically, when using a 32 bit application to write to Windows 8.1 64 bit registry for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, the writes are redirected to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`.  The problem is not with Lua nor Lua winapi.  The problem was with my understanding.

Comment: Can you expand on what your misunderstanding was? this would help make your answer useful.

Comment: When using a 32 bit application to write to Windows 8.1 64 bit registry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, the writes are redirected to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\VirtualStore\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node.